# Methods to an existing matlab class

Tags: matlab, class, methods

```
classdef BasicColors < Simulink.IntEnumType
  enumeration
    Red(0)
    Yellow(1)
    Blue(2) 
  end
end
```

Can i add method to this class externally??
I tried searching mutliple posts but couldnt find required answer.

I am trying to add method to this class outside this class definition in Matlab. Any thoughts??

Comment: Not possible. What are you trying to achieve? there must be a better way.

Comment: Create another class which will have an object `BasicColors` as one of it's properties. Then write your methods for this class.

Comment: I want to add method of same details to many other classes.

Comment: Not familiar enough with simulink, but in Matlab, you can simply add another superclass.

Comment: Can i add another class into properties. I tried this it seems not working @Hoki

Comment: Can you tell me how some example @Jonas

Comment: @UshaswarnaKiranmayi "I want to add method of same details to many other classes" sounds like this means copy pasting a lot of code. The usual ways to solve these problems are either the way hoki suggests is to create a class that have an object of the wanted class. Otherwise you can create a class that can inherit from the used class. So to say you can create a class `extendedColors` that extends the other class and add some functionality. The best way depends on what you want to do. Then you can use this class instead of the other for any application.

Comment: Can you show how i can write this code @ Patrik

Comment: I was trying to do it but i dont for somereason i may be writing wrong code. need some example to understand how to write in those two ways @patrik

Comment: @UshaswarnaKiranmayi I am not very used to working with classes in MATLAB. The comment was more or less about object oriented programming in general. I assumed that you knew about creating classes in MATLAB and needed advice regarding the design. Anyway, I think you need to describe the problem a little better. Since you created an enum class I would assume that you only want to scope the (in this case) colors. That is normally the purpose of enum classes. This makes it hard for us to guess how you want to use this function. Anyway, I think all member methods must defined inside the class.